# How do I use MorphSVGPlugin?

Tags: svg

I want to use `.convertToPath()` to convert some primitives such as circle, rectangle, etc. I am doing it like this -

```
MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath(circle);
```

but I am getting the error that

> MorphSVGPlugin is not defined.

Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: It looks like you didn't import MorphSVGPlugin. Please post more code so we can see the context.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but the prob has got solved. thanks for the help.

Comment: You should consider posting an answer describing how you solved the problem, in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the es5 method of loading.

A couple things to know -

It's very picky about the directory location relative to each other.  You need to have

```
TweenLite.js
plugins/MorphSVGPlugin.js
```

Link here -
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/9203-adding-plugins/?tab=comments

The other thing I ran into, is that if you use 'require.js', it must be loaded AFTER any plugins lest you get this -

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add the following additional script after loading all java-script scripts--

```
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin3.min.js"></script>
```